# Android: Unclicked notification timeout

Tags: android, notifications

I'm launching a notification on the weekend. If the notification is not seen/clicked after a certain time, I would like it to disappear by itself.
I couldn't find any way to set a timeout or something of the sort within the `NotificationCompat.Builder` expression. Here is the (quite normal notification builder) code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not_bar_small_icon)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Green))
                .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.strNotificationTitle))
                .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.strNotificationMessage))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notifyManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Can this be done?

**Solution Update:**

Solved using Aleksandar's link suggested in the comment below.

Comment: `AlarmManager` can help may be

Comment: @Prashant is correct.
See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874203/create-an-android-notification-with-expiration-date

Answer (score 6):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTimeoutAfter(long)

you can specify a duration in milliseconds after which this notification should be canceled, if it is not already canceled.