# AlarmManager not waking up a BroadcastReceiver after the specified time

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have notifications that work perfectly. These notifications are created by the service.
When I'm trying to dismiss the notification when the user didn't tap on it for 3 minutes. I tried the solution by Karakuri here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23874764, but nothing happened. The alarm not working and the broadcast receiver is not called.

The alarm manager in service class:

```
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, n);
//set up alarm
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);                                        intent.setAction("com.example.example.action.CANCEL_NOTIFICATION");
intent.putExtra("notification_id", notificationId);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,180000,pi);
```

The broadcast receiver `onReceive` method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// do something
final String action = intent.getAction();
Log.d("Reciver","onReceive lunched");
if ("com.example.example.action.CANCEL_NOTIFICATION".equals(action)) {
int id = intent.getIntExtra("notification_id", -1);
if (id != -1) {
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(id);
Log.d("Noti "+id," canceled ");
}}}
```

I didn't deal with the alarm manager before. I researched to know the reason but I didn’t find, I hope anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Handler it's easier than using Alarm Manager.
Since you are working in Service, use a Looper

Here already accepted answers will guide you:

[Clearing notification after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994126/clearing-notification-after-a-few-seconds)

[Using Handler inside service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006889/using-handler-inside-service)

I hope I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` method instead of `alarmManager.set` if you need it to fire exactly at requested time.

Also, you set time wrong. It has to be `System.currentTimeMillis() + 180000` if you want alarm to fire 3 minutes from current moment.

Finally, check if you have added `SET_ALARM` permission and declared your broadcast receiver in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: i followed you instructions but the problem still there :(